# GET form restructure url

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have a form using the GET method and i'm currently redirected to this url

```
www.mysite.com/index.php?token=123&cl=page&searchparam=mysearchtext
```

And i want to trick the get method via htaccess to rewrite the url to this

```
www.mysite.com/index.php?token=123&cl=page&searchparam=anothertext
```

How can i do it without the header(location).

Comment: you can create a rewrite rule in your htaccess file, from where do you plan to get this another value of "anothertext" by the way

Comment: I'm not quite sure how i can do that, can you please help me?

Comment: WHat is relation between `mysearchtext and anothertext` and why do you want to make this rule in .htaccess? Why don't your fix your form?

Comment: i have a search form and i want to change if the input value equals with something i want to be redirect to something else